# Taking screenshot with custom coordinates

Tags: libgdx

I am working on a libgdx project. I have to take screenshot but not all the screen, only specific area of the screen. This area can be bigger than screen size. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zoom out your camera, position it were you want it, take screenshot, zoom back in and set the position back. The player won't see this.

If that doesn't work, render one frame with the zoomed out camera, take screenshot and then zoom back in. The player will only see a 'flash'.

Or just make some sort of animation, where you zoom out and back in.

Comment: Good idea but aspect ratio of screenshot depends. I can't crop image after taking screenshot as well.